# Dynamic array of parameters

Tags: postgresql, rust

I have to build, in rust-postgres, a runtime-built select, with a variable number of parameters (the user, at runtime, makes some choices, and I have to build the select with the parameters needed in this very moment), so I can not have a

```
let baz = true;
let buzz : String = "ABCDE".to_string();
for row in client.query("SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz = $1 and buzz=$2", &[&baz, &buzz])?
```

Because I don't know, at compile time, what is the number or the type of the parameters.
Maybe one time I have 3 parameters, of different types, and one time 6 parameters.

I tried defining an array like

```
let mut parameters : [&[()]; 4];
```

But I can't put in this array a reference because the compiler reports me "mismatched type", and because I can't know the number of parameters.
How can I solve it?

EDIT: i explain my needs.
We have an home-made erp, and it has a HUGE amount of statistical query made for the needs of marketing/accounting offices.
But they asked a more free ability to make query, and my boss asked me to make a QBE application.
When this application starts, it shows a list of the DB tables.
when the users click on a table, the app shows the list of the fields in this table, and he/she can check some fields, and set the value for the search.
Example: the user choose the "workers" table.
The next form shows the list of the fields: name, surname, birthday, department, and so on. The user then click on NAME field and a windows appears, so he can input "JOHN", then click on the "department" field and input "R&D". then click the RUN button, and the application execute a

```
SELECT ... FROM workers where name = {} and department = {}
```

so i need that the number of parameters to be variable, and the TYPE of the values to be variable at runtime.

Comment: I assume you have taken care of building the query string and now you just need to figure out how to pass the parameters, right?

In that case, use a `Vec` instead of an array.

Comment: This is probably somewhat more tricky than "use a `Vec`". Yeah, you can use a `Vec<&(dyn ToSql + Sync)>`, but where do you store the things that are referenced? You might be able to use a `Vec<Box<(dyn ToSql + Sync)>>` and hand an iterator over that to `query_raw`. But ultimately, I think @Rottame needs to make an a bit more elaborate example, e.g. show where the query and parameters come from, and how to get a variable number of parameters with differing types.

Comment: @Caesar i edited the man question to add the actual needs. I saw "query raw" but i would to know if there is a "cleaner" way to do it. thank you!

Comment: Aah, [now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70660975/storing-disparate-sqlx-types-in-a-vector/70683840#70683840) I know why this problem felt familiar. (But it's sqlx, so it's even more tricky…)

Answer (score 3):

First, you need something to store the user input. `Vec` works great for this:

```rs
let mut inputs = Vec::new();

while let Ok(input) = get_input() {
    inputs.push(input);
}
```

Then, you need to turn this `Vec` into `&[&(dyn ToSql + Sync)]` so that you can pass it to `query`. Since it wants references, we leave ownership to the original `Vec` and make a new `Vec` with the references:

```rs
let mut inputs_dyn: Vec<_> = inputs
    .iter()
    .map(|input| input as &(dyn ToSql + Sync))
    .collect();
```

You can now pass this to `query` as a slice:

```rs
client.query("SELECT $1 FROM $2", inputs_dyn.as_slice())?
```

---

If you have values of different types, you can change the first `Vec` to hold `Box<dyn ToSql + Sync>`:

```rs
let mut inputs: Vec<Box<dyn ToSql + Sync>> = Vec::new();

while let Ok(input) = get_input() {
    inputs.push(Box::new(input));
}
```

The rest should still work, although it may be clearer to change `map` since they're already the correct trait object, just in `Box` instead of `&`:

```rs
.map(|input| input.as_ref())
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! does it works even with different data types? if i push a string and then a i64 it returns me a type mismatch error

Comment: It will if you box them. I'll add that in.

Comment: Looks like you have a `Vec` of `Vec`s? Try calling `flatten` before `map`.

Comment: sorry, i made a mistake copying the code, it works perfectly! thank you very much!